# How to update database with ajax/javascript without refreshing page asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I want to change the value of an enumdropdownlist from active to inactive in my database by doing some ajax call **WITHOUT** refreshing my page? How do I do this? javascript method or ajax.beginform? not sure here...

I tried ajax.beginform and the call gets made the to the controller ok, but then it tries to refresh/render a view by returning it as a actionresult. I don't want it to refresh the view because I loose my viewmodel data. I thought ajax.beginform only refreshed what was inside the form? Do I need to perform this in a javascript method instead?
What do I do to prevent a view from being refreshed/rendered in my action method?

here is my ajax form. If I return a view I loose all the 'Model' view data, so model.statusenabled is null! I don't understand why its null because it's outside of the ajaxform...

```
@if (Model.StatusEnabled)
      {
          using (Ajax.BeginForm("UpdateStatus", "Student", new AjaxOptions
          {
              HttpMethod = "post",
              OnSuccess = "dotcolor();"
          }))
          {
              @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.Status, new { @class = "btn btn-default btn-lg dropdown-toggle", onchange = "this.form.submit();", id = "enumstatus" })
          }
      }
      else
      {
         @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.Status, new { @class = "btn btn-default btn-lg dropdown-toggle", disabled = "disabled" })
      }
```

here is my action method

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult UpdateStatus()
    {
        //update database
        // don't return view because it gets refreshed
        // and I have to re pass in my viewmodel
        return View("Edit"); 
    }
```

if I change the return type to void in UpdateStatus() it still attemptsto return a view called UpdateStatus. Not what I want.

Comment: It sounds to me like you should be using [WebAPI](http://www.asp.net/web-api) and not regular MVC controllers/actions.

Comment: should I be doing this in just a javascript method then? I'm not using webapi in my project.

Comment: `Ajax.BeginForm` refreshes (replaces, perpends or appends) the contents of the element to specify in the `UpdateTargetId` of the `AjaxOptions` (which you have not specified). But you `if` block does not make sense - the `else` statement renders a `<select>` outside the form - which makes me think all this is enclosed in another form element (nested forms are invalid and not supported)

Comment: no this isn't nested inside any other form. I intentionally removed it from another form so it was independent. I don't need to replace/perpend/append anything in the form, I just need to update the database without refreshing the screen. Should this be in a javascript method using ajax inside it instead of a ajax.beginform?

Comment: Are you wanting to pass the selected value of the dropdown (I assume they are "Active" and "Inactive") to a method and then update the status of the Student in the database?

Comment: yes that is what I'm trying to do. Without refreshing the page. Or at least just refreshing a small part, not the whole page. Nothing needs to be refreshed/perpended/appended on the page so don't need to refresh anything it seems like

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is relatively easy using jquery and ajax to post the selected value

Html

```
@Html.EnumDropDownListFor(m => m.Status, new { @class = "btn btn-default btn-lg dropdown-toggle" })
```

Script

```
var id = '@Model.ID'; // store the ID of the student (change to suit your property name)
var url = '@Url.Action("UpdateStatus", "Student")';
$('#Status').change(function() {
  var status = $(this).val();
  $.post(url, { ID: id, Status: status }, function(data) {
    // do something with the returned value e.g. display a message?
    // for example - if(data) { // OK } else { // Oops }
  }
}
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UpdateStatus(int ID, EmployeeStatus Status) // assumes the enum is typeof EmployeeStatus 
{
  // update the employees status based on the parameters
  return Json(true); // or return Json("some message")
}
```

Note, you will probably want to check that the status was indeed updated, for example in a catch block you might `return Json(null)` or `return Json("some error message")` which you could then use to display a message on the page

Comment: so I run this in a javascript function right? Not in a ajax.beginform?

Comment: Yes, Just delete the `Ajax.BeginForm` stuff. Ensure you have jquery loaded and place this script inside `<script>` tags immediately before the closing `</body>` tag (or inside a `$(document).ready() {` function

Comment: Just a side note: Its not a usual interface to have selecting an option directly call a controller, and is likely to be confusing to the user. I would recommend an additional button (say 'Update Status') and handle the button's `.click` event rather than the select's `.change` event