# Change form field when another changes using database

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Edit: The [suggested duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28595910) appears to be about changing the database based on the current state of the page. I'm trying to change the page based on the state of the database.

I have a form that looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZcuXL.png). The Date of Birth and Account Number fields are based off of the Patient's database entry. When I select a new patient, I want those two fields to change.

This can easy be done with a `$().change()` function combined with `.val()`, except I can't use JavaScript in the middle of my C# database query. I don't know how to get around this.

I would like to do this:

```
var patient = $("#PatientID");

patient.change(function () {
    $("#DoB").val(@db.Patients.Find(patient.val()).DateOfBirth);
    $("#AccNum").val(@db.Patients.Find(patient.val()).AccNum);
});
```

But obviously the `patient.val()` is not valid there.

As far as I know, passing the values to a controller and returning a new view would save the model prematurely, which I want to avoid, in addition to refreshing the page, which is a UX no-no.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to update database with ajax/javascript without refreshing page asp.net mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28595910/how-to-update-database-with-ajax-javascript-without-refreshing-page-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: Hi As a suggestion  i will say that, write a jquery ajax and get the value of accnum and dob by providing patient id to the controller action method    , finally just update that new value with text box using jquery.Then It wont refresh the page and you will get what you want. Thanks karthik

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got it a bit off.

The JavaScript as well as HTML and CSS is part of the client side.
If any change is happening, you should fire an ajax request back to the server, with the value from the drop down.

```
$('#PatientID').change(onPatientChange);

function onPatientChange(eventData) {
    console.log($(this).val());
    // Ajax call should be placed here, and when the data is received
    // you should replace it with the old text boxes.
    // using $('#DoB').val(VALUE-RETURNED-BY-SERVER);
}
```

Comment: I don't suppose you'd be kind enough to replace `// Ajax call...` with the actual Ajax call? Do I use `$.post`?